# TabBar delegate, How to wait the end of particular NSThread before loading view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing a TabBar based application, the first view being load is a webview, during this time my app delegate is parsing a pretty big xml in NSThread, i'd like to block one specific view Controller from being load from my Tabbar until my NSTread finish his job. I'have implemented Tabbar method delegate "didSelectViewController" in AppDelegate, when i select a tabBar's item this method is call but i don't know what to do with this! Could someone help me?
Regards.
Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I find out!
I wrote :

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"occasions"])
    {
        if ([grabImage isFinished]) return YES;
        else return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

grabImage is my NSTread.